# How to add columns in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am currently trying to add up the data in my database and display the value however I am having trouble doing so. 
this is the code I have used so far.

```
package com.example.alzheimersdetector;

import com.google.firebase.database.Exclude;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class faqinputs {
    private double questionOne;
    private double questionTwo;
    private double questionThree;
    private double questionFour;
    private double questionFive;
    private double questionSix;
    private double questionSeven;
    private double questionEight;
    private double questionNine;
    private double questionTen;




    public faqinputs(double questionOne, double questionTwo, double questionThree,
                     double questionFour, double questionFive, double questionSix, double questionSeven, double questionEight, double questionNine, double questionTen) {
    this.questionOne = questionOne;
    this.questionTwo = questionTwo;
    this.questionThree = questionThree;
    this.questionFour = questionFour;
    this.questionFive = questionFive;
    this.questionSix = questionSix;
    this.questionSeven = questionSeven;
    this.questionEight = questionEight;
    this.questionNine = questionNine;
    this.questionTen = questionTen;

}
public faqinputs() {

}



public double getQuestionOne() {return questionOne;}

public void setQuestionOne(double questionOne) {
    this.questionOne = questionOne;
}



public double getQuestionTwo() {
    return questionTwo;
}

public void setQuestionTwo(double questionTwo) {
    this.questionTwo = questionTwo;
}




public double getQuestionThree() {
    return questionThree;
}

public void setQuestionThree(double questionThree) {
    this.questionThree = questionThree;
}




public double getQuestionFour() {
    return questionFour;
}

public void setQuestionFour(double questionFour) {
    this.questionFour = questionFour;
}




public double getQuestionFive() {
    return questionFive;
}

public void setQuestionFive(double questionFive) {
    this.questionFive = questionFive;
}





public double getQuestionSix() {
    return questionSix;
}

public void setQuestionSix(double questionSix) {
    this.questionSix = questionSix;
}




public double getQuestionSeven() {
    return questionSeven;
}

public void setQuestionSeven(double questionSeven) {
    this.questionSeven = questionSeven;
}




public double getQuestionEight() {
    return questionEight;
}

public void setQuestionEight(double questionEight) {
    this.questionEight = questionEight;
}




public double getQuestionNine() {
    return questionNine;
}

public void setQuestionNine(double questionNine) {
    this.questionNine = questionNine;
}




public double getQuestionTen() {
    return questionTen;
}

public void setQuestionTen(double questionTen) {
    this.questionTen = questionTen;
}
```

}

The data is successfully being stored in firebase. It is being saved under a User node.

```
package com.example.alzheimersdetector;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import static android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O;

public class Results extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    private Button generate;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);
        generate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.generate);
        //Get a reference to the Firebase Database
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        GetUserScore();
    }

    private void GetUserScore() {
        String UserId= fAuth.getUid();
        Query totalResultQuery = mDatabase.child("FAQ").child(UserId);

        // [Start basic_query_value_listener]
        // sum of user's results

        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                double count = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    double total = dataSnapshot.child("FAQ").getValue(Double.class);
                    count = count + total;
                }
                Log.d("TAG", count  + "");
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        totalResultQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

    }
}
```

So I am trying to add up questionOne to questionTen then display the result.

The code builds then I run the application and it crashes, I get this error in the "Run"

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.alzheimersdector, PID: 28399 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.alzheimersdector/com.example.alzheimersdetector.Results}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getUid()' on a null object reference

Comment: Whats the problem you are facing with this code ?

Comment: The code builds then I run the application and it crashes, I get this error in the "Run" "E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.alzheimersdector, PID: 28399
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.alzheimersdector/com.example.alzheimersdetector.Results}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getUid()' on a null object reference"

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a `NullPointerException` on

```
String UserId= fAuth.getUid();
```

This happens because your code doesn't initialize `fAuth` before calling `getUid()` on it.

To fix this, you'll probably want to initialize `fAuth` in `onCreate`, like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);
    generate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.generate);

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); // this line is new

    GetUserScore();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry for the late response. Big help!!